# Tablix not showing DataSet created using a "custom" IEnumerable

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I want to print a report based on the datasource list of a DataGridView.

I want to use Rdlc reports for this. I created the report, put a tablix in it with a DataSet named "DataSet".

Then, in the report viewer, I just delete that DataSet, and add a DataSet with the same name that contains the list(`IEnumerable`) I wanted. The problem is that the Tablix is not showing anything. I looked in the internet but can´t find anything related to it. Also, how can I make fields visible or invisible using the ReportViewer?

This is my code (it is in the Form´s Load event:

```
Sistema_financiero_Entities db = new Sistema_financiero_Entities();
IEnumerable<Cheque> cheques = db.Cheque.Where(x => x.id_cheque != 6).ToList();

ReportDataSource data = new ReportDataSource("DataSet", cheques);

try
{
    this.rpt_Viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data);
    this.rpt_Viewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

Some considerations: db is the Entity framework object context. cheques is the list (in this example I´m just taking data from the db, but I will use the DataGridView datasource list, I did this just to test if this was working). rpt_Viewer is the reportViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `IEnumerable<Cheque> cheques = db.Cheque.Where(x => x.id_cheque != 6).ToList();`

to

`List<Cheque> cheques = db.Cheque.Where(x => x.id_cheque != 6).ToList();` worked perfectly.